# Showing a captured image onClicked

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a robot that has a camera, which I use to capture image and view it on QT Application. The camera output is three [40][40] arrays for RGB colors respectively. I have tried QPaintEvent but it cannot be used as a slot and I found it like inventing the wheel.

```
gui::EpuckImage image = this->epuck->cameraShot();
int r[40][40],g[40][40],b[40][40];
for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
            image.getRGB(i,j,r[i][j],g[i][j],b[i][j]);              
    }
}
```

So, I have 40 x 40 RGB Pixels.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event, int r[40][40], int g[40][40], int b[40][40]){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::DiagCrossPattern);
    QPen pen;
    QColor color(100,0,0, 255);
    pen.setColor(color);
    pen.setWidth(5);
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
            QColor color(r[i][j],g[i][j],b[i][j], 255);
            pen.setColor(color);
            painter.setPen(pen);
            painter.drawPoint(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use this code to draw the pixels on click

Comment: PS: Post the C++ code
PS I love you? 

Comment: Capture image to pixmap and call [update](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) slot. Then in [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) paint the pixmap.
PS: [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html)